# Intialize inner class variable from a different class

Tags: class, wrapper-class

I am bit confused on accessing the inner class variable from a different. I have created a class structure to serialize and create a json request. I need to send an custom object with attachment.

```
public class outerclass {
public string Name;
public string Department;
public list<innerclass> incls;

public class inneClass {
     public string attachmentbody;
     public string contentType;
 } }
```

Now , I need to intialize the variable. I can easily create the instance of the outer class and assign the value. but , how should I do it for inner class. I am doing it in a third class.

```
public thirdClass {
function (){
   outerClass OC = new Outerclass ();
   OC.name =  'John';
   OC.Department = 'sales';
   OC.incls = ?? 
  }
}
```

How can I initialize this list, add multiple instance for inner class. It's like John sales records has mulitple attachment, but how can I have multiple instance for inner class and attach it to outer class instance. thanks.

Comment: hi .. Can someone help me with this ? Do i need to custom controller for the inner class to initialize it's member.

Comment: `OC.incls = new List<outerclass.innerClass> ();`  followed by lines such as `OC.incls.add(new OuterClass.innerClass(..constructor args..));`  Your innerclass needs a constructor or setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I m not sure if I misunderstood your question. to initialisation the inner class collection you have, it will be same as you create any other list and add element into it..

```
public thirdClass {
function (){
   outerClass OC = new Outerclass ();
   OC.name =  'John';
   OC.Department = 'sales';
   List<Outerclass.innerClass> incls = new List<Outerclass.innerClass>();
   for(Iterate your JSON array){
       Outerclass.innerClass inc = new Outerclass.innerClass();
       inc.attachmentbody = '';
       inc.contentType = '';
       incls.add(inc);
   }
   oc.incls = incls;  
  }
}
```

---

this is what i tried in my dev org which works

**Class 1 :**

```
public class OuterClass {

    public Integer outerInt;
    public List<innerClass> icList;

    public class innerClass{
        public String testMe;
    }
}
```

**Class 2 :**

```
public class hello {

    public string testInnerClass(){
        OuterClass oc = new OuterClass();
        oc.outerInt = 1;
        oc.icList = new List<OuterClass.innerClass>();
        OuterClass.innerClass ic = new OuterClass.innerClass();
        ic.testMe = 'test';
        oc.icList.add(ic);
        return 'success';
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't initialize inner class like this.   ist<innerClass> incls = new List<innerClass>() & innerClass inc = new innerClass()  won't work.. Try it yourself ...

Comment: not sure what you are doing, but wen i tested, it works fine. only thing i missed is when you access the innerClass, you have to go thu the outerClass

Comment: Go through the outer class means.. write innerClass inc = new innerClass()  in outer class ..correct...Yeah ..thats true. in Outer class we can write./access  innerclass inc = new innerClass.. but I have to access it from the third class.

Comment: I hv updated the code that i tested in my dev org.. i dont get any errors. can u let me know wat error you get when u use this code or your code ?

Comment: Thanks Vamsi.  Although , I have tried the same approach earlier , It didn't work.. but your post made me give it try again . and it worked.. Thanks a lot